# In Symfony 3.4.11, I get a crash after adding access control

Tags: symfony, authentication, roles

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7moK.png)Here is my security.yml:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Here is my error:

[image: Symfony error]

It says the YAML file is not valid. How can I proceed?

Comment: Please always post [your errors as text, not as an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) (you may additionally post an image if you wish).

Comment: I wonder if we would need to see the whole of this file, not just these lines. Is there any other YAML?

Comment: Could you show us your whole file ? It could be any character in your YAML

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7moK.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yml file should be indented correctly.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: I pasted the author's YAML [into a parser](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) and found they get the same result regardless of whether they use theirs or yours.

Comment: it could be any character in your yml file

Comment: thank you for your answer but I do not know how to do that , Can you explain more to me?

Comment: comment section doesn't support indentation, so please paste like you did previously or replace your existing code.

Comment: thanks well I worked now after adding the code manually do not copy paste